# iphone: a local server to test my app

Tags: iphone, lamp

the app that i'm developing, needs to interact with a server, to accomplish some operations: save user's data, retrieve data about other users, services and so on...
before paying to rent some space on a server, i'd like to test my app making it interact with a server located on my computer, simulating a real a LAMP server as a localhost.

did you ever tried to do the same? can you suggest me a LAMP server that i can use locally?
do you suggest any other solution in place of the one i'm seeking?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

While the server is running make your requests to your own IP address.  I'm fairly confident this will work while you are using the simulator, and likely it will also work from an app.

In terms of finding LAMP server software for the mac... you should check out [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) which allows you to simulate a server on your mac.

Comment: If you are already familiar with XAMPP on another platform [XAMPP for Mac](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) is another good solution for running a local LAMP server. Making requests to localhost or 127.0.0.1 from the simulator should work once you have a local server set up.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion
i used in the past xampp for simulating a joomla-based web site. a friend of mine suggested to avoid it and use another one, maybe it was mamp. what's your opinion about them both? is there any substantial difference?

thanks for help

Comment: I have never used XAMPP but I found MAMP easy enough to set up and run (and this was when I was first learning PHP/MySQL and had no idea what  I was doing at all).